# No internet for Chrome/Opera if not logged through GDM but Firefox is OK

Tags: google-chrome, internet, systemd, gdm

If I don't use a graphical-display manager (GDM,LightDM, etc...) then I don't get access to internet for Chrome/Opera but only with Firefox.

Do you have an idea?

Also, is there any doc about graphical-display manager mechanism since systemd inception?

Thank you

Comment: Please include what version of Ubuntu you are experiencing this with. Also, if you don't use a display manager, how are you starting up X11 or Wayland?

Comment: Latest. ubuntu 18.04 LTS
It is not something new, it happens also on Xenial and Debian 9.

Comment: Please answer the second question as well:  If you don't use a display manager, how are you starting up X11 or Wayland?

Comment: X11, the good ol' way -> startx

Answer (score 0):

The display manager must be setting up some networking that `startx` is not.

Login both ways and run `systemctl status --user` and save the output for side by side review. If the login manager method has started some extra services, they are likely related. Two services involved with setting up networking are `NetworkManager` and `systemd-networkd`.

Also check your `.bash_profile`. It is executed only for the CLI logins and not for the display manager login. If it did something like setup HTTP proxies, that could be the difference as well.

Comment: Hi Mark,

the only diff from the dbus.service, which I think is the most relevant, are:

- gconfd-2  
- goa-identity-service  
- goa-daemon  
- dconf-service  
- gnome-keyring-daemon  
- xdg-desktop-portal

Comment: Still no solution. 
Somehow, Chrome is unable to resolve any website, using IP is working so it is really a matter of DNS resolving.

This is the only err thrown in the console.  

 [8450:8482:0818/163843.792740:ERROR:nss_util.cc(748)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
[8450:8482:0818/163843.793676:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(981)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for www.google.com failed err=-5992
[8450:8480:0818/163843.823495:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(981)]

Comment: @Phil2.0, What was the result of the side-by-side review the and checking your .bash_profile?